# Piping continuous output into rofi

Tags: bash, shell, dmenu, rofi

I'm trying to write a bash script to pipe strings into rofi. These strings are continuously generated by a function `gen_x`.

The function `gen_x` sometimes (only when a condition is met) outputs new strings. I currently implement the `gen_x`-function with an if statement within an infinite loop.
I want to pipe this function into rofi. When an item is selected within rofi, rofi should output the selected item and `gen_x` and rofi should end.

When using an infinite loop which outputs a new element every loop (as seen in `gen_b`), the script does exactly what I described above.
However, when I implement an if statement in my function and only print a new element when the condition is true, the program never ends. I am unsure if this is due to `gen_x` or rofi.

Simplified code

```bash
gen_a(){ while true; do if [[ "$v" == "" ]]; then echo "Test"; v=1; fi; sleep 1; done }
gen_b(){ while true; do                             echo "Test";            sleep 1; done }

gen_a | rofi -dmenu # -> this outputs Test and does not end
gen_b | rofi -dmenu # -> this outputs Test and ends properly
```

Is there a way to use conditionals within the while-loop, and the program ending properly.

Comment: Please explain what you are expecting to happen, what you really need to do, because it isn't clear from your script. What does `rofi -dmenu` expect as input? What exactly are you trying to pipe to it? Neither of the functions you show would ever exit unless you kill them since both are `while true` with no exit condition.

Comment: your first steps seem nonsense regarding your problem. Please explain how this could contribute to the solution

Comment: I reworded the post and took out the irrelevant parts. I hope it's better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rofi` doesn't *switch to async mode* before it has read 25 lines of input by default. That can be changed with the:

> `-async-pre-read [number]`       Read several entries blocking before switching to async mode

option.

So:

```
cmd | rofi -async-pre-read 1 -dmenu
```

For it to display a menu as soon as one line has been read from `cmd`.

When an item is selected, `rofi` will print it and terminate.  `cmd` will be killed by a SIGPIPE thereafter the next time it writes something to stdout (which is now a broken pipe) as usual.

To kill it straight away, the common approach is to do:

```
sh -c 'echo "$$"; exec cmd' | {
  IFS= read -r pid
  rofi -async-pre-read 1 -dmenu
  kill -s PIPE "$pid"
}
```